# Sending text information in a p2p network

Tags: javascript, networking, port, p2p

I have been attempting to create a simple peer to peer network for quite some time. 
I stumbled upon a javascript example found [here](https://github.com/marcelklehr/smokesignal) that I have been working from.

When I run the example found in the repository, the peers never make a connection. I am beginning to wonder if there are problems with the ports I am attempting to use. When I use a port checker online, I can see that most of my ports are stealthed.

**Questions:**

- Do my ports need to be open (not stealthed) to communicate on a P2P network?
- How would I go about opening ports?

I have started an issue that describes my problem in more detail found [here](https://github.com/marcelklehr/smokesignal/issues/22)